# htaccess RewriteRules Colliding

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

Having a real brain teaser here. 
Everything works fine like it should until I get to 
mysite.com/index.php?page=XXX&parent_url=XXX&child_url=XXX
Then I get this error

Warning: include(browse/12-oclock-bars/cbr-600-f4i.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/leb/public_html/index.php on line 167

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'browse/12-oclock-bars/cbr-600-f4i.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in /home/leb/public_html/index.php on line 167

But the first two lines are working fine. Why would the 3rd line not work for my site. But if I comment out the first two lines, than the third line works.... I'm so confused.

Here is my HTACCESS file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php?
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1&parent_url=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1&parent_url=$2&child_url=$3 [L,NC]
```

---

*-------------------------------------------*
Revised with new problem below

Here, Line 3 won't work, but all the others do, If I change its position up or down, the others stop working.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1&parent_url=$2&child_url=$3product=$4 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1&parent_url=$2&child_url=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1&parent_url=$2&product=$3 [L,NC]  <---
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1&parent_url=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Looks like I had to reverse the order of my rewrite rules, works now. Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: This looks to be more of a PHP problem than a rewrite problem. The directory "browse" isn't on the include path. What's the location of the absolute location of the script causing the warning? What's the absolute location of "browse"?

Comment: Its definitely a htaccess problem. I revised my original post.. Look at line 3 listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jeroen commented, there is no difference in the incoming URLs for rules 2 and 3.  Although the intended page they are supposed to go to is different, the incoming URLs you are checking for in both rules is still `/a/b/c`.  If you had some indicator in the URL, say for Rule 3, being a product:

```
 RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=product&parent_url=$2&product=$3 [L,NC]
```

With that change, as your rules are currently, that rule would have to come before your current 2nd rule.

Also, when matching sections like this, I find it much easier to use `([^\/]*)` instead of `(.*)`.  This way, the group matches everything up until the `/` and you will notice less dependence on the ordering of your rules.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Helped greatly   Very simply and quick fix, until I become as knowledgeable about htaccess, as I am with PHP lol. THANK YOU SO MUCH!  

RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=product&parent_url=$1&child_url=$2&product=$3 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=product&parent_url=$1&product=$2 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^browse/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=browse&parent_url=$1&child_url=$2 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^browse/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=browse&parent_url=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC] MUCH

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 and line 3 look for the same pattern, so execution will terminate at line 2 and never reach line 3 in case of a match.

Comment: How would I go about separating them so everything works? or is there a simpler way to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dave Without any identifiers in the url, it´s hard to determine whether your third parameter is of type `child_url` or of type `product`. Is there a clear distinction between the two, like for example `child_url` always starts with `http`?

Comment: Yes, index.php?page=product&parent_url=exhaust-systems&product=akrapovic-slip-on

Comment: compared to index.php?page=browse&parent_url=exhaust-systems

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the conclusion that it is easier to deal with the url in PHP.

You can pass the whole path with the following code in htaccess:

```
# pass url path as get variable via "path"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In PHP you can explode the path:

```
//Assuming $_GET['path'] = 'this/is/an/example/';

// Trim extra '/' off right side
$path = rtrim($_GET['path'],'/');

//explode the path by "/"
$pathArray = explode("/",path);

echo $pathArray[0]; // outputs "this"
echo $pathArray[1]; // outputs "is"
echo $pathArray[2]; // outputs "an"
echo $pathArray[3]; // outputs "example"

// It is sometimes easier to work with a path in reverse:
$reversedPathArray = array_reverse($pathArray);

$page = $reversedPathArray[0];

echo $page; // outputs "example"
```

Comment: I see what you are saying. I will give it a try and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: @Dave - Sounds good. It has made things easier for me, just thought I'd pass the tip along :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing **(.*)** by **([^/]+)**:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1&parent_url=$2&product=$3 [L,NC]
```

And do the same thing for every line.